# Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'undefined' is null or not an object

Tags: javascript

I have a following javascript

```
(function() {
    try {


        var stdin = WScript.StdIn.ReadAll();
        var json = eval('(' + stdin + ')');
        var log = new Log(json.environment.actionLogFile);
        log.commenced();
        var inputFilePath=json.action.inputs[0].value;
        log.info("inputFilePath : "+inputFilePath);
        ................
        log.completed();
    } catch (e) {
        log.info("error");
    }
})();
```

This gives me error, `Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'undefined' is null or not an object` in `catch`. Any suggestions why this happen?

Comment: Without knowing what you're inputting and what `log` is? Nope. I mean, at a guess, `log` is `undefined`.

Comment: `'undefined' is null`? What a weird error message!

Comment: @Vohuman: *"**or** not an object"*

Comment: @Teemu: This is WSH anyway, so the DOM won't really relate.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I saw that part. But that's still a weird error message.

Comment: @Vohuman: Well...Microsoft... :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, O've updated the question

Comment: ...and provided half of the information requested. :-| Again: What's your input?

Comment: I don't think `Log` is a standard WSH object, is it? Normally they're prefixed. Where are you getting `Log` from?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown what input you're providing, but at a guess I'd say that your code is throwing an error prior to or on the `var log = ...` line, most likely from the `eval` call (if the input can't be evaluated) or the `new Log(json.environment.actionLogFile);` call (if it can but doesn't result in an object with an `environment` property, `new Log` throws for some reason). That means that control transfers to the `catch`, which tries to use `log`, which is `undefined`.